# Migrate TFS2010 to TFS2012 on a new machine

Tags: tfs-migration

I have TFS 2010 running on a fairly old machine and I want to both upgrade it to 2012 and move to a new machine.
Going through MSDN I couldn't find such upgrade path. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upgrade path from 2010 -> 2012 actually gets you to fully uninstall 2010, so the upgrade + migration to another box is pretty much the same, just with a db backup/restore added in.

Install TFS 2012 on a new box, take a backup of all the databases and restore them on the new sql server, run through the wizard like you're doing a simple upgrade on the current box.

http://blog.damianbrady.com.au/2012/06/03/upgrading-tfs2010-tfs2012-rc-done/

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. However it's important to notice that not all DBs should be restored to the new installation. Also you should backup and restore the OLAP DB separately from the SQL management App.